# making jfilechooser show image thumbnails

Tags: java, thumbnails, jfilechooser

I wanted to create a `JFileChooser` with thumbnail view of image files.So I subclassed FileView and in the method which creates `ImageIcon` did some scaling sothat thumbnail images are shown.

However,the overall effect is that, the `filechooser` widget takes some time before opening a directory and showing thumbnails..In createImageIcon() below,I need to call new ImageIcon() twice-once with the image filepath and next with the resized image as constructor argument.I think this is what slows the widget .

Is there a more efficient alternative?Any suggestions/pointers most welcome.

thanks,
mark

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    JFileChooser chooser=new JFileChooser();
    ThumbNailView thumbView=new ThumbNailView();
    chooser.setFileView(thumbView);
  }

class ThumbNailView extends FileView{
 public Icon getIcon(File f){
  Icon icon=null;
  if(isImageFile(f.getPath())){
   icon=createImageIcon(f.getPath(),null);
  }
  return icon;
 }
 private ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path,String description) {
  if (path != null) {
   ImageIcon icon=new ImageIcon(path);
   Image img = icon.getImage() ; 
   Image newimg = img.getScaledInstance( 16, 16,  java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH ) ;
   return new ImageIcon(newimg);
  } else {
   System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + path);
   return null;
   }
}

private boolean isImageFile(String filename){
    //return true if this is image
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was actually surprised to see that, despite using the native look & feel in Windows, the file chooser indeed doesn't have a thumbnail view.  I tried your example and you're going along the right lines, but I see how slow it was for folders with a lot of large images.  The overhead is, of course, due to I/O when reading the file contents and then interpreting the image, which is unavoidable.

What's even worse, is that I found out that `FileView.getIcon(File)` is called a **lot** - before the file list is shown, when you mouse over an icon, and when the selection changes.  If we don't cache the images after loading them, we'll be pointlessly reloading images all the time.

The obvious solution is to push all the image loading off onto another thread or a thread pool, and once we have our scaled-down result, put it into a temporary cache so it can be retrieved again.

I played around with `Image` and `ImageIcon` a lot and I discovered that an `ImageIcon`'s image can be changed at any time by calling `setImage(Image)`.  What this means for us is, within `getIcon(File)`, we can immediately return a blank or default icon, but keep a reference to it, passing it along to a worker thread that will load the image in the background and set the icon's image later when it's done (The only catch is that we must call `repaint()` to see the change).

For this example, I'm using an `ExecutorService` cached thread pool (this is the fastest way to get all images, but uses a lot of I/O) to process the image loading tasks.  I'm also using a `WeakHashMap` as the cache, to ensure that we only hold onto the cached icons for as long as we need them.  You could use another kind of Map, but you would have to manage the number of icons you hold onto, to avoid running out of memory.

```
package guitest;

import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.WeakHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileView;

public class ThumbnailFileChooser extends JFileChooser {

    /** All preview icons will be this width and height */
    private static final int ICON_SIZE = 16;

    /** This blank icon will be used while previews are loading */
    private static final Image LOADING_IMAGE = new BufferedImage(ICON_SIZE, ICON_SIZE, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

    /** Edit this to determine what file types will be previewed. */
    private final Pattern imageFilePattern = Pattern.compile(".+?\\.(png|jpe?g|gif|tiff?)$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

    /** Use a weak hash map to cache images until the next garbage collection (saves memory) */
    private final Map imageCache = new WeakHashMap();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        JFileChooser chooser = new ThumbnailFileChooser();
        chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        System.exit(1);
    }

    public ThumbnailFileChooser() {
        super();
    }

    // --- Override the other constructors as needed ---

    {
        // This initializer block is always executed after any constructor call.
        setFileView(new ThumbnailView());
    }

    private class ThumbnailView extends FileView {
        /** This thread pool is where the thumnnail icon loaders run */
        private final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

        public Icon getIcon(File file) {
            if (!imageFilePattern.matcher(file.getName()).matches()) {
                return null;
            }

            // Our cache makes browsing back and forth lightning-fast! :D
            synchronized (imageCache) {
                ImageIcon icon = imageCache.get(file);

                if (icon == null) {
                    // Create a new icon with the default image
                    icon = new ImageIcon(LOADING_IMAGE);

                    // Add to the cache
                    imageCache.put(file, icon);

                    // Submit a new task to load the image and update the icon
                    executor.submit(new ThumbnailIconLoader(icon, file));
                }

                return icon;
            }
        }
    }

    private class ThumbnailIconLoader implements Runnable {
        private final ImageIcon icon;
        private final File file;

        public ThumbnailIconLoader(ImageIcon i, File f) {
            icon = i;
            file = f;
        }

        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Loading image: " + file);

            // Load and scale the image down, then replace the icon's old image with the new one.
            ImageIcon newIcon = new ImageIcon(file.getAbsolutePath());
            Image img = newIcon.getImage().getScaledInstance(ICON_SIZE, ICON_SIZE, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
            icon.setImage(img);

            // Repaint the dialog so we see the new icon.
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {public void run() {repaint();}});
        }
    }

}
```

Known issues:

1) We don't maintain the image's aspect ratio when scaling.  Doing so could result in icons with strange dimensions that will break the alignment of the list view.  The solution is probably to create a new `BufferedImage` that is 16x16 and render the scaled image on top of it, centered.  You can implement that if you wish!

2) If a file is not an image, or is corrupted, no icon will be shown at all.  It looks like the program only detects this error while rendering the image, not when we load or scale it, so we can't detect this in advance.  However, we might detect it if we fix issue 1.

Answer (score 6):

Use `fileDialog` instead of `JfileChooser` for choising the image:

```
FileDialog fd = new FileDialog(frame, "Test", FileDialog.LOAD);
String Image_path

fd.setVisible(true);
name = fd.getDirectory() + fd.getFile();
        image_path=name;
        ImageIcon icon= new ImageIcon(name);
        icon.setImage(icon.getImage().getScaledInstance(jLabel2.getWidth(),jLabel2.getHeight() , Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
        jLabel2.setIcon(icon);
```

Comment: Suggesting AWT in a Swing question in 2012? Eww…

Answer (score 0):

You could use a default icon for each fileand load the actual icons in another thread (perhaps using a SwingWorker?). As the icons are loaded the SwingWorker could call back and update the FileView.

Not sure if a single SwingWorker would do the trick, or whether it would be better to use one for each icon being loaded.