# include image thumbnails in jfilechooser

Tags: java, swing

i have a jfilechooser that aids in searching and selecting image for upload into project database. and there's a thumbnailator class that compresses the uploaded image into the desired size. the code is as follows for a button action_performed to run the file chooser:

```
private void jButton13ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    try{
    String sql = "delete from TempImage";
    pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);
    pst.execute();
    }catch(SQLException | HeadlessException e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }finally{
                try{
                    rs.close();
                    pst.close();
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                }
            }
        JFileChooser chooser =new JFileChooser();
        chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        File f =chooser.getSelectedFile();
        filename=f.getAbsolutePath();
        image1.setText(filename);

        try{
            File imgs =new File(filename);
            BufferedImage bufferedimage=ImageIO.read(imgs);
            BufferedImage thumbnail=Thumbnails.of(bufferedimage)
            .size(125, 114)
            .asBufferedImage();
            ByteArrayOutputStream os = new  ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ImageIO.write(thumbnail,"jpeg", os);
            InputStream is=new ByteArrayInputStream(os.toByteArray());
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new  ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte[] buf =new byte[1024];
            try{
                for(int readNum; (readNum=is.read(buf))!=-1;){
                    bos.write(buf,0,readNum);
                    System.out.println("Read" +readNum+ "bytes,");
                }
            }catch(IOException ex){
                Logger.getLogger(null);
            }
            person_image=bos.toByteArray();
        }catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }finally{
            try{
                rs.close();
                pst.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
            }
        }
        try{
        String sql="insert into TempImage(Image)values(?)";
        pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setBytes(1, person_image);
        pst.execute();
        }catch(SQLException | HeadlessException ep){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ep);
        }finally{
            try{
                rs.close();
                pst.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e){

            }
        } 
        try{
         String sql ="select Image from TempImage";
            pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs=pst.executeQuery();

            if(rs.next()){
                byte[] imagedata = rs.getBytes("Image");
                format =new ImageIcon(imagedata);
                image.setIcon(format);
            } }catch(SQLException | HeadlessException e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            }
       finally{
            try{
                rs.close();
                pst.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
            }
        }// TODO add your handling code here:
    }
```

what this code does is to delete image from 'temp image table' insert a compressed chosen image from filechooser into 'temp image table' and a jlable displays the chosen image selected from the computer for preview, before the user final accepts and saves the chosen image into the database permanently.
but when the filechooser is opened, I want all image files to be in thumbnail view before the user selects his choice.
please how do I include image thumbnails in jfilechooser??

Comment: Just clarigying, you want your user to view all options of images he/she can save as in Windows large icon view?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [making jfilechooser show image thumbnails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096433/making-jfilechooser-show-image-thumbnails)

Comment: when fileChooser opens, all files are in list formats before you select what you want. I don't want the files to be in list formats. I prefare a thumbnail view of the files. the main purpose of using the filechooser is to upload images. so I like all files not to be in list formats but in thumbnail view before the image file is choosen @jreznot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way to do that using JFileChooser. The Metal look and feel is very limited. The Metal Look and Feel only offers a list like arrengement of files, it does not use the Windows interface, so you would have to use another technology.

As in this [possible duplicated question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096433/making-jfilechooser-show-image-thumbnails), you can achieve it throught a *hackish* way. Another solution is to use **FileDialog** instead of **JFileChooser**. The FileDialog class uses the look and feel of the current operating system, using its components rather than arraging it by its own criteria, so your user would be able to view it as a LargeIcon, if he/she wants to. You can find its documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FileDialog.html). A sample follows:

```
FileDialog fileDialog = new FileDialog(yourJFrame, "Choose a file", FileDialog.LOAD);
fd.setDirectory("the directory you want the dialog to be opened in");
fd.setFile("*.desiredExtension");
fd.setVisible(true);
String filename = fd.getFile();
if (filename == null)
    //your user cancelled the choise
else
    //file chosen
```

Comment: Changes have been made, @AndrewThompson. Thanks for adding info!

Comment: @RodneyNart don't forget to check the answer as correct if it works, This way more people with this same problem will be reached.

Comment: sure @Pelicer have been  a bit busy so haven't tried it out yet. will surley do that today and give u feed back

Comment: Please, do so. If you want I have some personal projects that might help you.

Comment: so what projects are they bro. kindly send me your email address