# How do I display a thumbnail of large images in a JFileChooser without running straight into a Java heap space error?

Tags: java, swing

I have customized a JFileChooser to render something similar to Windows explorer with large icons to help to choose the desired image. To avoid switching back and forth from windows explorer to the JFileChooser to know which file to pick up, I want to display the images directly in the JFileChooser.
The code works but is not good as runs straight into an out of memory issue (java heap space).

```java
public class ThumbnailFileChooser extends JFileChooser {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public ThumbnailFileChooser(File file) {
        super(file);
        setFileView(new ImageFileView());
    }

    class ImageFileView extends FileView {
        private static final int ICON_SIZE = 128;

        @Override
        public String getTypeDescription(File f) {
            String extension = getExtension(f);
            String type = null;

            if ((extension != null) && (extension.equals("jpeg") ||
                extension.equals("jpg") ||
                extension.equals("png"))) {
                type = "Image File";
            }
            return type;
        }

        // Cache for storing icons of files
        private Map<File, Icon> iconCache = Collections.synchronizedMap(new LinkedHashMap<File, Icon>() {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry<File,Icon> eldest) {
                return size() > 100;
            }
        });

        @Override
        public Icon getIcon(File f) {
            String extension = getExtension(f);
            Icon icon = null;

            if ((extension != null) && (extension.equals("jpeg") || extension.equals("jpg") || extension.equals("png"))) {
                // If the icon is in the cache, use it. Otherwise, load the icon in a background thread.
                icon = iconCache.get(f);
                if (icon == null) {
                    SwingWorker<Icon, Void> worker = new SwingWorker<Icon, Void>() {
                        @Override
                        protected Icon doInBackground() throws Exception {
                            Image img = ImageIO.read(f);
                            Image scaledImg = img.getScaledInstance(ICON_SIZE, ICON_SIZE, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
                            return new ImageIcon(scaledImg);
                        }

                        @Override
                        protected void done() {
                            try {
                                // When the icon is loaded, store it in the cache and update the file chooser.
                                Icon icon = get();
                                iconCache.put(f, icon);
                                ThumbnailFileChooser.this.repaint();
                            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                                ex.printStackTrace();
                                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                            } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
                                ex.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    worker.execute();
                }
            }
            return icon;
        }

        private String getExtension(File f) {
            String ext = null;
            String s = f.getName();
            int i = s.lastIndexOf('.');

            if (i > 0 &&  i < s.length() - 1) {
                ext = s.substring(i+1).toLowerCase();
            }
            return ext;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [making jfilechooser show image thumbnails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096433/making-jfilechooser-show-image-thumbnails)

Comment: I have the same memory leak issue with the code from  this answer

Answer (score 1):

I see two main issues that could influence the heap usage in your code:

1. If your  method `getIcon(File)` gets called multiple times for the same instance of `File` while the first call is not yet finished and therefore no instance is in the cache, each time a new worker will be started and replaces the previous workers work. If the `file` is not yet in the cache, try to fill the cache immediately, best with a default image, and the worker should replace the content of the image when it's finished.
2. You instantiate an anonymous inner class for the worker, that keeps a reference to the complete dialog. Try to extract this into an `static class` (inner or not, as you prefer), and just pass the necessary references to it. This would be the `File f` for which you want to create the icon, and either an instance of the cache or an instance of the previously created default image to replace its contents if you worked on the finding in item 1.